# Intel 8265/67 Wifi card not working after fresh lubuntu/xubuntu installation,

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have recently migrated from windows donțt know much about linux, this has irritated me so much as simple as wifi thing isnt right.
In additional driver it is showing device is not working, continue using installed driver and one option is greyed out.
Help me someone please.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your release (nor if you've installed Lubuntu or Xubuntu; it's unclear). We don't know what option is greyed out, nor if you've connected an ethernet cable to allow packages to be installed from the internet (we don't know what OS/release you're using so it's very unclear).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that your Wi-Fi driver is not in the version of the Linux kernel you are on.

Try installing the latest updates (of course, you will need to use a Wi-Fi card that works on your Linux kernel version, or connect to your router via Ethernet, to do this).

If that doesn't work, try updating to a mainline (not officially provided by your distro yet) Linux kernel (again, you will need to use a Wi-Fi card that works on your Linux kernel version, or connect to your router via Ethernet, to do this). I made a YouTube video that shows you the easiest way to do this. Click [here](https://youtu.be/GYxhjemxDOU) to watch.

If that still doesn't solve your problem, you can either look for a Linux driver for your Wi-Fi card, or simply wait for a Linux kernel version that supports your Wi-Fi card. In the latter case, you will probably want to use a Wi-Fi card that is supported by Linux, or connect to your router via Ethernet, while you're waiting.

Comment: The driver for the Intel 8265-series has been in the Linux kernel for several generations. Something else is wrong.

Comment: I did update everything tho...with apt-get update. btw thanks for making that video.